# Jquery fullscreen image with borders

Tags: jquery, image, window, fullscreen

I have some code which gives me a fullscreen image which is kept in its original proportions (ie. landscape is fully stretched width ways and portrait height ways). I need to be able to have varied borders around the page (ie top:100,left&right:120,bottom:200) that the image will stop at and not encroach into. Is there an easy fix with what I have?

Any help is appreciated!

```
 function FullScreenBackground(theItem,imageWidth,imageHeight){
    var winWidth=$(window).width();
    var winHeight=$(window).height();

    var picHeight = imageHeight / imageWidth;
    var picWidth = imageWidth / imageHeight;

    if ((winHeight / winWidth) > picHeight) {
        $(theItem).attr("width",winWidth);
        $(theItem).attr("height",picHeight*winWidth);
    } else {
        $(theItem).attr("height",winHeight);
        $(theItem).attr("width",picWidth*winHeight);
    };

    $(theItem).css("margin-left",(winWidth-$(theItem).width())/2);
    $(theItem).css("margin-top",(winHeight-$(theItem).height())/2);
}
```

Dear lord....someone help me please!!

The answer from Swatkins did give me the borders, but the image is not scaled in constraint proportions.

I am using this great plugin from Malihu:
http://manos.malihu.gr/simple-jquery-fullscreen-image-gallery

but just trying to put varied borders around the image as I said above.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but you might try:

```
function FullScreenBackground(theItem,imageWidth,imageHeight){
    var winWidth=$(window).width();
    var winHeight=$(window).height();

    var picHeight = imageHeight / imageWidth;
    var picWidth = imageWidth / imageHeight;

    if ((winHeight / winWidth) > picHeight) {
        $(theItem).attr("width",winWidth - 240);
        $(theItem).attr("height",picHeight*winWidth - 300);
    } else {
        $(theItem).attr("height",winHeight - 300);
        $(theItem).attr("width",picWidth*winHeight - 240);
    };

    $(theItem).css("margin-left",(winWidth-$(theItem).width())/2 + 120);
    $(theItem).css("margin-top",(winHeight-$(theItem).height())/2 + 100);
}
```

This should decrease the height and width by the totals of the margins, then offset the top and left with the margins needed for those.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is definatley a little better but still not quite right. You can see my edit to link and fiddle for full code if you would like to take a look, cheers.

Comment: worked by dropping the (+120 & +100) of the css margins! Cheers

Comment: Great! Sorry I hadn't had a chance to try it out. Glad you found the fix.

Answer (score 1):

Check the fiddle here :
http://jsfiddle.net/leifparker/CSS5e/2/

This image will resize on click. The border margins are set according to a data-attribute (fullmargins) attached to the *img*. It follows regular margin shorthand (top, right, bottom, left) in pixels.

It is presently animating, but you can turn the delay on the animate to 0 for an instantaneous resize.

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://www.airhorns.co.uk/imgs/85/klaxon_chrome.jpg" data-fullmargins="10 20 10 20" class="background_sizer_image" >
```

**Jquery**

```
function FullScreenBackground(theItem){
    var imageWidth = theItem.width();
    var imageHeight = theItem.height();

    var theItemMargins = theItem.data('fullmargins').split(' ');
    var heightMarginDifference = parseInt(theItemMargins[0]) + parseInt(theItemMargins[2]);
    var widthMarginDifference = parseInt(theItemMargins[1]) + parseInt(theItemMargins[3]);

    var widthProportion =  imageWidth / ($(window).width() - widthMarginDifference);
    var heightProportion =  imageHeight / ($(window).height() -heightMarginDifference);

     if (widthProportion > heightProportion){
         theItem.animate({ width  : (imageWidth / widthProportion) ,
                           height : (imageHeight / widthProportion) }, 150)
     } else {

         theItem.animate({ width : (imageWidth / heightProportion) ,
                           height : (imageHeight / heightProportion)  }, 150)
     }
}

$('.background_sizer_image').click(function(){ FullScreenBackground($(this))});
```